# html select suppress default style

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to totally supress the default html select appearance ?

All I want to show is the selected value. It should look like a normal html text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some javascript(jQuery)

```
 $("#selectId").replaceWith("<p>" + $("#selectId option:selected").text() + "</p>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not entirely... the browser style will still be present, much like a scroll bar. This will vary from browser to browser as you would expect also.

Answer (score 0):

as **BoltClock** said, the rendering of standard form elements depends on your browser and OS. But there are many jquery scripts to replace standard form elements, like this: http://india.assigninfo.com/assignlabs/samples/jALDropDown1_7_3/App_Web/jAlDropDown_compare.htm.

Maybe this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 property but it's look to be compatible with webkit only for the moment

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

You have JavaScript option for exemple with jQuery : http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#basic